# environment_json: PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN with cf events and also in backend DB ccdb - howto see value?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Howto see the exact diff that was done?

```
$ cf events example
Getting events for app example in org example / space exampe as example...

time                          event              actor              description
2017-01-11T08:56:22.00+0100   audit.app.update   example@example.com   state: STARTED
2017-01-11T08:51:58.00+0100   audit.app.update   example@example.com   environment_json: PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN
```

Also in CCDB there is the value `environment_json: PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN`. Howto see the exact diff customer made?

With `cf env` I see lots of `User-Provided` and `Running Environment Variable Groups` parameters. For example `JAVA_OPTS` or `JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE`

We use API version: 2.65.0

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way that you can see the diff, at least not from the audit log.  The values are intentionally masked out because the env variables often contain sensitive information.  Darn you security!  It sadly makes the audit logs less than helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To see all details of events, the user account must have `cloud_controller.admin` privileges. Without, you can only see details allowed at the privilege level assigned to the user.

You can try [cf get-events](https://github.com/ECSTeam/cf_get_events) plugin.